# How to close the database connection in Android

Tags: android, sqlite

Currently working on database part of android project. The main aim of the project is to parse  the XML file and store the database as its parsing. I am opening the database and inserting the data in database. But when I try to change the activity it crashes on close() function of database.
I know I am doing something wrong here. If anyone can help me here it will be great.

/****DatabaseManager.java****/

```
    SQLiteDatabase db;
public DatabaseManager(Context context){
    this.context = context;

    db = context.openOrCreateDatabase(DATABASE_NAME, 0, null);
    }

    public void close(){
    if ( db != null )
    {
        db.close();
    }
    }
```

/*****Activity.java*****/

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    try{
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        DB = new DatabaseManager(this);
     }
  }

 public void onDestroy(){
     super.onDestroy();

    if(DB!=null)
        DB.close();
 }
```

Errors:

```
 E/Database(676): close() was never explicitly called on database '/data/data/org.com.android/databases/MainSQLite.db' 
enter code here
```

Comment: Just guessing, but shouldn't you close the `DB` first, and then call `super.onDestroy()` ?

Comment: I reverted the code by calling DB.close() first and then super.OnDestroy() but still it fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code you are closing out the Db correctly because of you are calling super.onDestroy(); before the code gets to call the db.close() method.

Try calling it outside the onDestroy() method.

Comment: outside the onDestroy() meaning where should I call ideally ?

Comment: You should call it outside of onDestroy for instance, when you are finished with your Database just call db.close().

Comment: I would strongly encourage you to not use onDestroy(), it is not always called especially when the system is reclaiming resources. I generally use onStop and onResume to control such things.

Comment: thanks...I didnt realize I had two handlers for it. Very bad of my coding grrr...

Answer (score 0):

this is what im duing :-)

```
private DbHelper ourHelper;



private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }}

public void close(){
     ourHelper.close();
 }
```